# Stop user input after word has been found in textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea, maxlength

I'm trying to put together something seems so simple but for some reason I can't get the `return false;` to work correctly.  I am trying to stop the user from entering anymore text after the word "img" is found three times.  The `return false;` doesn't work for some reason.  I have everything working in my demo except how to stop the user from typing.  Any help would be great.

DEMO: [jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/2cAeX/](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/2cAeX/)

```
$('#test').keyup(function(e){
var v = $(this).val(),
    w = v.split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/),
    word = 'img',
    c = 0;
for (var i=0,len=w.length;i<len;i++){
    if (w[i] === word){
        c++;
    }
    if(c == 3){
    return false           
    }
}
$('#output').text(c);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using keyup is a bit late, as the key has already been pressed:

```
$('#test').keypress(function(e){
    var v = $(this).val(),
        w = v.split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/),
        word = 'img',
        c = 0;
    for (var i=0,len=w.length;i<len;i++){
        if (w[i] === word){
            c++;
        }

    }
    if(c == 3){
        return false           
    }
    $('#output').text(c);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cAeX/3/)

Here's an easier way:

```
$('#test').on('keypress', function(e){
    var word  = 'img',
        count = this.value.match(new RegExp('\\b'+word+'\\b','g')) || [];

    $('#output').text(count.length);
    return count.length < 3;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cAeX/5/)

**EDIT:**

As a requirement seems to be to be able to use backspace, keypress can't be used as it doesn't register backspace.
However, keydown will, and with some clever magic we can do:

```
$('#test').on('keydown', function(e){
    var word  = 'img',
        count = this.value.match(new RegExp('\\b'+word+'\\b','g')) || [];

    $('#output').text(count.length);
    return !(count.length > 2 && e.which != 8); // 8 is backspace
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cAeX/6/)

Comment: Thank you! It totally slipped my mind. Don't know how I forgot about keypress.  Now the only other problem is to let them use the backspace to delete the text.  Is that possible now that we have called `return false`?

Comment: @ryan - nope, pressing backspace won't be possible like that, I'll add a solution for that as well.

Comment: very nice! Hats off to you! Works like a charm.